# Cookie not sent with requests for embedded resources

Tags: cookies, browser, samesite

I'm having trouble figuring out why my requests to embedded resources on a webpage aren't using a cookie that's stored for that site.

The scenario is:

Website 1: abc.com (Cookie 1)
Website 2: 123.com (Cookie 2)

abc.com has a script resource hosted at 123.com. abc.com has a Cookie 1 that is correctly being sent along with the request for the page. The request for the embedded script is not sent with the Cookie 2 that is stored in the browser. If I browse to the link for that script directly, the request is sent with Cookie 2 correctly. Also note that the cookies are stored with SameSite=None to allow them to be sent cross-site.

Browser third-party cookies are enabled. The developer tools don't show any blocked cookies in the request for the script.